# Why are the hidden settings-folders not deleted when purging an application?

Tags: package-management, apt, settings, purge

I did

`sudo apt-get remove --purge`

for several packages, but apparently the personal settings are kept. Is there a command or tool to delete them automatically?

Comment: The command should now be `sudo apt-get purge`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you mean the folders in your home folder: No, the package manager never touches anything in a users's home folder.

I don't know of any tool that assists you in cleaning your home folder from config files you don't need any more - but that sounds like a nice idea.

Comment: What about sudo apt-get purge mentioned by @Cas in his comment?

Comment: @MestreLion `sudo apt-get purge` removes global config files (usually somewhere in `/etc/`) not removed by `sudo apt-get remove` but still doesn't touch the user's home folder

Comment: Wow... I didnt know that! I always used Synaptics instead of Software Center to remove a software because i thought that "purge" would be the cleanest way, and it purged everything. That means most of my ~/.folders are orphaned garbage. Thats sad! :(