# How do I completly remove software?

Tags: uninstall, purge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are the hidden settings-folders not deleted when purging an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42564/why-are-the-hidden-settings-folders-not-deleted-when-purging-an-application)

Ok I have 8GB on my desktop dual booting win 7.
I installed a few games, assualtcube, tremolous, and spring. But I had removed them using 'remove --purge' and only to find they are still lingering and purge does not well truly purge them. I need them completely gone and not secretly hogging space when I purged them. How can i completely remove software, like it is gone and not going to take any more of my precious space?
Shrinking 7 and growing Ubuntu is not an answer I am accepting, i want to know how to completely remove software.

Thank you for your time and your answers.

Comment: 'sudo apt-get remove --purge PKG' should (and I believe does) completely remove every file installed by the package (unless there is a packaging error). It does not remove files created during *use* of the pkg.

Comment: is it just 'sudo apt-get remove --purge PKG' or do I have to put the softwares name after PKG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using the `sudo apt-get remove --purge` to uninstall the software then, you can use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to get rid of the residing none-useful files.